# NetSuite Scriptlet Not Reading Items from Shopping Bag

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I'm augmenting a scriptlet that handles shipping methods for a NetSuite web shopping cart.  The goal is to read in the shopping cart items and detect the presence of two items.  If the items are present in the cart and if the shipping country is not the US, we want an alert shown.  The function is as follows:

```
function shipPoster(){
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var ctr = "carttablerow" + i;

if (ctr.NameNumber in ('5454','5458')){
    if (shpCty != "US"){
        showtext ="These item(s) cannot be shipped outside the United States.  Please remove these items prior to check out."
    }
    goShip()
    }   

}
```

I've deployed the script and tested with the items in question.  However, the alert is not thrown.  How can I modify the above to ensure the cart items are read and the alert is triggered?  Also, how do I prevent the user from proceeding?  Is there a way to remove the item from the cart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(ctr.NameNumber in ('5454','5458')) ....

I'm not familiar with this syntax, can you show the code? I assume you are prototyping the string object NameNumber, but why are you passing the numbers with parenthesis?

To work on your question, if you are working in console, put console.log() after every step and see where it is failing.

Comment: What would be the most appropriate way of limiting script to select just the two item numbers listed?  I included a bit of pseudo code as am unsure of syntax here.

Comment: You have to do the if comparison by getting there, use using jQuery or some other DOM traversing. Should be pretty straightforward,  Google "jQuery val"

Answer (score 0):

If I've got your question correctly, you want to restrict users on few items to be shipped outside USA and want to restrict them on further processing on the record.
For this
1. You need to create client script.
2. Deploy it on the record like sales order 
3. Do it like following
if (ctr.NameNumber in ('5454','5458')){
    if (shpCty != "US"){
        alert "These item(s) cannot be shipped outside the United States.  Please remove these items prior to check out."
        return false;
    }
    goShip()
}

When you return false, user will have to acknoledge the error and can remove the items and proceed again